# Unix mv *.* moves also subdirectory

Tags: linux, mv

I have a main directory *main_dir* and subdirectories *v1*, *v2*, *v3* all containing the same files. I rename *v3* : `mv v3 v3_old` and recreate it `mkdir v3`. My jobs then create the files in *main_dir*.

Up to this point all looks as expected.

The command `mv *.* v3` (from *main_dir*) moves the files, as expected, **but also *v3_old*** inside *v3*. (I have always used `mv *.* v...` when moving files from *main_dir* to *v...* and it has always worked just fine before this renaming).

As expected, *v1* and *v2* are not moved.

Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*.*` looks like a DOS habit to select files excluding directories. In a modern filesystem, it will select all items in the current directory that include a `.` in their name. I guess the actual name of your directory "v3_old" contains a period character.

If you can't find a pattern matching sequence matching files only, you can see this answer to move files only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147290/move-every-file-that-is-not-a-directory

Else, you can use a directory name without a period for v3_old, if using `*.*` is your habit. Other habits can be e.g. to have filenames starting lower case and directory names with upper case : then `mv [a-z]* v3` will do. (It also makes directory navigation with autocompletion easier)